# How can I force a local copy of an image to be used instead of fetching from a third party site

Tags: image, caching, redirect, pagespeed, image-compression

I have a website which uses a couple of third party JS plugins. Google page speed insight is reporting that some of the images that are being served from these third party sites are not compressed, but I have no control over these.

Is there some way that I can create a local compressed copy of the images and force these to be served instead of the third party one?

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't be possible.

For better option you download third parties JavaScript plugin in your local environment and after that you are able to compressed image and use it in your website.